# Esxi remote machine automation

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, vmrun

My requirement is to automate an `esxi` remote machine using java.

So, I am able to automate `vmware` workstation and fusion by creating a bat file where I have added all the `vmrun commands` and executing the bat file using java.

**Can anyone help me in achieving the same for `esxi` remote machine where I am using commands (like `vmrun`) for opening a browser in remote machine and passing the `url`.**

I think `vmrun` utility is no longer supports for `esxi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`powercli` module of `powershell` solved my problem